# Docker hangs while pulling

Tags: macos, docker

I am trying to run `docker run docker/whalesay cowsay boo` from the tutorial.

Here is the output I get:

```
Unable to find image 'docker/whalesay:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from docker/whalesay
e190868d63f8: Already exists
909cd34c6fd7: Already exists
0b9bfabab7c1: Already exists
a3ed95caeb02: Pulling fs layer
00bf65475aba: Already exists
c57b6bcc83e3: Already exists
8978f6879e2f: Waiting
8eed3712d2cf: Download complete
```

It has been 10 minutes but nothing shows up. Is it supposed to take that long?

I tried control+C and re-run the command, and restarting Docker Quickstart Terminal. It's still not solving the problem.

Comment: Does `docker pull docker/whalesay cowsay boo` terminates?

Comment: @vmonteco `docker pull docker/whalesay` does not terminate either.

Comment: So it doesn't download the whole image? Do you still have space on disk?

Comment: @vmonteco I am able to successfully pull other images on docker hub, so it's not a disk space issue. Is there a way to re-pull ignoring downloaded files?

Comment: Do you have docker/whalesay in your images?

Comment: Nope, `docker images` has nothing in it.

Comment: nothing like "not a single image" or nothing like "not docker/whalesay"?

Comment: It only has the `hello-world` image from previous tutorial steps.

Comment: What if you delete all images and try to pull `docker/whalesay` again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109600/discussion-between-wolfpwner-and-vmonteco).

Comment: FYI, reinstalling docker from scratch solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reinstalling docker from scratch solved the problem for me

Comment: Before reinstall, you might to try restart the docker service using ```sudo systemctl restart docker.service```

Comment: Restart does the work. thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 19):

You don't have to reinstall. Just restarting docker service should do

`service docker restart`

Comment: For linux users, just restarting docker service solved.

```sudo systemctl restart docker.service```

Comment: Clicking Restart from the Docker Desktop for Windows tasklist icon did it in my case.

Answer (score 9):

Similar situation. I got the feeling that concurrent download caused the problem. So I just force the docker downloading connection to 1.

docker-icon -> perferences -> daemon -> add the following code:

```
{
  "max-concurrent-downloads": 1 
}
```

slower but more stable.

Answer (score 1):

I also was getting stuck on the "Pulling fs layer" when pulling images, and just want to add another reason it might be happening (this was what happened to me): I was connected to my corporate network and needed to set proxies; once I set the proxies, the image pull finished fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem because of antivirus program. After I've disabled it (to disable it quickly, I just renamed McAfee installation directory and rebooted) - Docker finally was able to pull all layers.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed boot2docker long ago (March 2016), and this was overshadowing Docker for Mac. I had to manually uninstall boot2docker.

Answer (score 0):

set env for docker daemon

```
MOBY_DISABLE_PIGZ=true
```

Comment: Please improve your answer by explaining it and /or providing a citation